# Can I encapsulate entity framework model logic into the model itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When working with Entity Framework, I make standard C# classes for each of my desired Models. So, if I have a Car Model, it might look like the following:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

And to manage the Car Models inside of my database, I create a `DbContext` class with a `DbSet<Car>` property inside. This is great, but I feel like that extra `DbContext` class is not necessary. Is there a way to write my `Car` Model class in a way that it, itself, manages its own `DbSet<Car>`?

```
public class MyDbContextClass : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of the following work flow:

```
var db = new MyDbContextClass();
var cars = db.Cars.ToList();
```

I'm trying to see if it's possible to use the following work flow:

```
var cars = Car.ToList();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Definitely possible but what are the benefits?

Comment: Not sure of any benefits other than cosmetic; reducing lines of code and need to create that context class. Perhaps just so I can keep all the Car-specific code in the Car class, as well.

Comment: Data retrieval is not entity specific. It is the responsibility of yet another class, the db context. Domain entities should be unaware of the way they are stored/retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the `DbContext` in such a way, but it will probably make you implement more then you intended in order to make it work while loosing performance.

I think **you better keep it the way it meant to be**, as I can't see any benefits doing it as you mentioned. 
You are coupling the `DbContext` to the models and trying to make super-objects - Objects that are in charge of Data representation and Data access layer.

This leads to a bad design and against the [**Separation of Concerns Principle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Don't be tempted to decrease the number of code lines in the price of bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want something called Active Record Patterns. EF is not design with this pattern in mind. Insteda of forcing it to do this, maybe just use another ORM instead? Like http://www.castleproject.org/projects/activerecord/